# C Prog - File Handling Limits

Tags: c

I am trying to make a recording system wherein I want to sign in, login with my employee ID and password, or if possible, just the employee ID. The problem is, whenever I place the employer ID's into a text file, my code limits me only of the predefined usernames on my code. How can I make every employer ID present in a text file be accepted and can log in successfully?

```
        #include <stdio.h>
    #include <conio.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <conio.h>

    void mainMenu();
    void EnterItem();
    void ViewItem();
    void SearchItem();
    void Exit();

    int count=1,ulength,plength;
    char username[]="Admin",password[]="1234";
    char name1[10],pass[10];

    char code[20],name[20],search[20];
    int price,qty;
     main(){

     printf("\nEnter USer ID And Password below(You have Only Three Chances!\nPress Enter To Continue" );
      getch();
      while(count<=3)
      {

      printf("\nENter User ID:");
      scanf("%s",name1);
      printf("\nENter Password:");
      scanf("%s",pass);
      ulength=strcmp(name1,username);
      plength=strcmp(pass,password);
      if(ulength==0&&plength==0)
      {
      printf("\nWelcome %s",name1);
      break;
      }
      else
      {
      printf("\nUsername And Password is Invalid!\n You Have %d more Chances/s.",3-count);
      }
      getch();
      count++;
      }
      if(count==4)
      printf("Maximum of three(3)Try only!");
      getch();




        mainMenu();
        EnterItem();
        ViewItem();
        SearchItem();
        Exit();
         getch();
         }

    void mainMenu(void){

    char choice;
    printf("\t*************************************\n");
    printf("\t******========================*******\n");
    printf("\t******==!!INVENTORY SYSTEM!!==*******\n");
    printf("\t******========================*******\n");
    printf("\t*************************************\n");
    printf("\n");

    printf("\nMenu:\n[a]EnterItem\n[b]ViewItem\n[c]SearchItem\n[d]Exit\n");
    printf("What do you want to perform?:");
    fflush(stdin);

    scanf("%c",choice);
    switch(choice){

    case 'a':
        EnterItem();
        break;
    case 'b':
        ViewItem();
        break;
    case 'c':
           SearchItem();
        break;
    case 'd':
        Exit();

        break;
    default:
        printf("Invalid Choice");

        }
    }

    void EnterItem(void){

    FILE *MyFile;
    char opt;
    do{
        printf("Enter Item Code:");
        fflush(stdin);
        scanf("%s",code);

        printf("Enter Item Name:");
        fflush(stdin);
        scanf("%s",name);


        printf("Enter Item Price:");
        fflush(stdin);
        scanf("%i",&price);


        printf("Enter Item Quantity:");
        fflush(stdin);
        scanf("%i",&qty);
            MyFile=fopen("MyFiles.txt","a+");
            fprintf(MyFile,"%s\t%s\t%i\t%i\n",code,name,price,qty);
            printf("Item Saved!!\n");

        printf("Do you want to Add More?:[y/n]");
        fflush(stdin);
        scanf("%c",&opt);


    }while(opt=='Y'||opt=='y');
    printf("Do you want to Go Back To main?:[y/n]");
    fflush(stdin);
    scanf("%c",&opt);
    if(opt=='y'||opt=='Y')
    mainMenu();
    else
       printf("Invalid Choice!!");

         }

    void ViewItem(void){

    FILE *MyFile;
    int c;

    if((MyFile=fopen("MyFiles.txt","r"))==NULL)
    {
    printf("Error Reading File!!");

    }
    while((c=fgetc(MyFile))!=EOF)
    printf("%c",c);
    printf("Go to Main Menu[y/n]:");
    fflush(stdin);
    scanf("%c",opt);
    if(opt=='y'||opt=='Y')
    mainMenu();
    else(); 
    fclose(MyFile);
    getch();
    }

    void SearchItem(void){

    FILE *MyFile;

        MyFile=fopen("MyFiles.txt","a+");
        printf("Enter the Item Code to Search:");
        fflush(stdin);
        scanf("%s",search);
        while(!feof(MyFile))
        {
        fscanf(MyFile,"%s %s %i %i",code,name,price,qty);
            if(strcmp(search,code)==0)
            {
            printf("Item Code: %s\n",code);
            printf("Item Name: %s\n",name);
            printf("Item Price: %i\n",price);
            printf("Item Quantity: %i\n",qty);
            break;
            printf("Go Back To main Menu[y/n]:");
            fflush(stdin);
            scanf("%s",opt);
    if(opt=='y'||opt=='Y')
    mainMenu();
    else
            }
           }
              fclose(MyFile);
    }

    void Exit(void){
    getch();
    }
```

Comment: done :) just edited the code.

Comment: In addition to the other bugs you're calling fflush on stdin, which will result in undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ulength=strcmp(name1,username);
     plength=strcmp(pass,password);`

This is limiting your ability to use only predefined usernames in your code. You are comparing it with username, which holds "Admin". So no matter what you enter as a username, you will always be comparing it to the string "Admin".

What you need to do is open the file containing the employee details using "fopen". And then you can read the employee details into an array (or another data strcture of your choice) using "fgets". You can iterate over the list and compare it with "name1".

Cheers,
VSN

P.S. Use strncmp as it makes your code more safe. If you are working on UNIX machine, you will find man pages for "fopen", "fgets" and "strncmp" besides other standard C functions.

Comment: wait, if i have to call it in an array, how would it continually read every data? would i store each file name inside the array?